# Using a library in Sublime Text

Tags: c++, c, sublimetext3, sublimetext, gmp

I want to compile with gcc a C program using the library GMP with Sublime Text as my text editor. I know that GMP is well installed because I'm able to use it with Code::Blocks.

However, I don't know how to specify to my compiler where it can find the library (I'm on Windows and the GMP folder is located at C:\gmp) and I keep getting the error :

```
fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory
>#include <gmp.h>
```

I tried to change the build system I used in Sublime Text to compile my programs to the following code :

```
{
    "cmd": ["gcc", "$file_name", "-I C:\\gmp", "-L C:\\gmp\\.libs", "-o", "${file_base_name}.exe", "&&", "${file_base_name}.exe"],
    "file_regex": "^([^:]+):([0-9]+):",
    "selector": "source.c",
    "shell": true,
    "working_dir": "$file_path"
}
```

but that doesn't work. It seems my compiler is unable to locate the GMP library. I’ve tried multiple combinations for the arguments but nothing works. I also tried to use the compiler flags I passed to gcc on Code::Blocks (since I have no problem using GMP with Code::Blocks) but it doesn't seem to work neither.

By removing the space after `-I` and `-L` I get this other error :

```
C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccE63Xzx.o:test.c:(.text+0x1e): undefined reference to `__gmpz_init_set_ui'
C:\Users\UTILIS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccE63Xzx.o:test.c:(.text+0x32): undefined reference to `__gmp_printf'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

and adding `-lgmp` I get :

```
c:\gmp\.libs/libgmp.a(doprntf.o):doprntf.c:(.text+0x701): undefined reference to `__gmpn_bases'
c:\gmp\.libs/libgmp.a(get_str.o):get_str.c:(.text+0x19c): undefined reference to `__gmpn_bases'
c:\gmp\.libs/libgmp.a(get_str.o):get_str.c:(.text+0x276): undefined reference to `__gmpn_bases'
c:\gmp\.libs/libgmp.a(lt20-get_str.o):get_str.c:(.text+0x18b): undefined reference to `__gmpn_bases'
c:\gmp\.libs/libgmp.a(lt20-get_str.o):get_str.c:(.text+0x224): more undefined references to `__gmpn_bases' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

So how can I specify to my compiler gcc where it cand find the GMP library ?

Comment: Just to clarify your question, Sublime doesn't know or care where your libraries are because it's just the editor you're using to edit the content of the file. It's your compiler (`gcc` in this case) that you need to provide this information to. The `sublime-build` file is the correct place to do this; are you sure you're using this build and not one of the built in ones?

Comment: @OdatNurd Ok I understand, thanks for your clarifications. Yes I've just checked again and I'm using this build, not another one.

Comment: as a best guess, I'd try removing the space between `-I` and the directory, like `"-Ic:\\gmp"` and see if if that helps (ditto for `-L` if that fixes the include problem).

Comment: @OdatNurd I tried but I still get the same error.

Comment: So just to verify, the full path to the header is `c:\gmp\gmp.h`? The above seems like it should work OK if that's the case.

Comment: @OdatNurd Yes, the header is `c:\gmp\gmp.h` and there is also `c:\gmp\.libs\libgmp.a`.

Comment: for what it's worth, you seem to be missing a `-lgmp` on your compile line if there's also a library that needs to be linked. What you have there seems like it should work, though. Does running that command manually from the terminal provide a different result? It may also be helpful if you could amend your question with the full build error output from Sublime.

Comment: @OdatNurd Adding `-lgmp` doesn't change anything (I didn't know where to put that argument so I tried different positions). I tried running the command directly from my terminal, but I get the same results. I edited my first post to be clearer. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That might not be the correct library name (I've never used `gmp` before), but the linker error you outlined above is because you're calling `gmp` functions without linking the library. I'd look in the folder you're specifying as the argument to `-L` for an appropriate library. On Linux it would be `libsomething.a`, which you'd link with `-lsomething`. You should be able to put it before the `-o` argument in the list.

Comment: @OdatNurd I think the library name is correct because in the GMP library I read "all programs using GMP must link against the libgmp library" and in c:\gmp\.libs there is the file libgmp.a. Moreover, when I change the `-L` argument for an incorrect folder, I get the error "cannot find -lgmp", which is not the case with the argument I wrote in my post. By the way, I edited my first post again with another error my computer returns when I add `-lgmp`.

Comment: are there more `.a` files in there? From those errors it looks like the code in `libgmp.a` is expecting to find other code that's not contained in the library.

Comment: @OdatNurd There is only one `a` file : `libgmp.a`. There are also `libgmp.la`, `libgmp.lai`, `libgmp.so`, `libgmp.so.10` and  `libgmp.so.10.4.0`.